# Inverse in ElGamal signature

Tags: elgamal-signature

I am learning about ElGamal signature verification. During the signature generation one has to choose a `k` such that `1 < k < p − 1` and `gcd(k, p − 1) = 1`. I am using the notation from the Wikipedia site. Later it is used the inverse of `k`. I assume this is a modular inverse. Learning materials I have found does not state whether this is a modular inverse regarding `p` or `p-1`. Can somebody clarify this?

Comment: Try both, see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ElGamal Signature Scheme we have:

$$\beta=\alpha^a \bmod p$$

The values $p,\alpha$ and $\beta$ are public key, and $a$ is private key.

$$\operatorname{sig_k}(x,k)=(\gamma , \delta)$$

> where $\gamma = \alpha^k \bmod p $ and $\delta = (x-a\gamma)k^{-1} \bmod {p-1}$.

Comment: The question was how k^-1 is calculated from k.

Comment: @franz1, from answer it's evident that $k^{-1}$ calculated from mod p-1.

Answer (score 1):

It is $p-1$.   I now give a detailed explanation as to why this is:

### 1. First, I give a corollary which is used to prove the ElGamal signature verification.

**Corollary** If $a$ and $p$ are relative prime integers, and $p$ is a prime integer,then $a^i \equiv a^j \pmod p$,where i and j are non-negative integers, if and only if $i \equiv j \pmod {p-1}$.

This corollary gives the relationship of $p$ and $p-1$.

One of the methods to prove it is based on a theorem.

This theorem can be found in *Elementary Number Theory and Its Application*, (6th ed.), by Kenneth Rosen (p. 349).   **Theorem 9.2**. It can also be used to prove DSA.

**Theorem 9.2** If $a$ and $n$ are relative prime integers with $n>0$, then $a^i \equiv a^j \pmod n$, where i and j are non-negative integers, if and only if $i \equiv j \pmod {ord_n^a}$

Specially, when $p$ is a prime integer, ${ord_p^a}=\varphi(p)=p-1$ , so we prove the corollary.

hence:

$$i \equiv j \pmod {p-1} \Leftrightarrow a^i \equiv a^j \pmod p.$$

### 2. Now, we review the ElGamal signature, and prove it using the corollary.

#### 2.1 Key Generation for an ElGamal Digital Signature

> 1. Choose a large prime $p$.
> 2. Choose a primitive element $\alpha$ of $Z_p^*$.
> 3. Choose a random integer $d \in \{2,3, . . . , p-2\}$.
> 4. Compute$\beta = \alpha^d \pmod p$.
>    The public key is $k_{pub}=(p, \alpha, \beta)$, and private key $k_{pr}=d$

#### 2.2 ElGamal Signature Generation

The signing consists of two main steps: choosing a random value $k$, which forms an ephemeral private key, and computing the actual signature of $x$.

> 1. Choose a random ephemeral key $k \in \{0,1,2, . . . , p-2\}$ such that $gcd(k, p-1) = 1$.
> 2. Compute the signature parameters:
>    $$r \equiv \alpha^k \pmod p$$
>    $$s \equiv (x-d\cdot r)k^{-1} \pmod {p-1}$$

Hence, the signature is:
$$sig_{k_{pr}}(x,k)=(r,s)$$

#### 2.3 ElGamal Signature Verification

1. Compute the value
   $$t \equiv \beta^r \cdot r^s \pmod p$$
2. The verification follows from:
   $$
   t\begin{cases}
   \equiv \ \alpha^x \pmod p\ \ \ \  \Rightarrow  \ \ \ \ valid \ \ signature\\\\
   \not \equiv \ \alpha^x \   \pmod p\ \ \ \  \Rightarrow  \ \ \ \  invalid \ \ signature
   \end{cases}
   $$

#### 2.4 Proof

Prove that:
$$ \alpha^x \equiv \beta^r \cdot r^s \pmod p$$
since:
$$ \beta^r \cdot r^s \pmod p \equiv (\alpha^d)^r(\alpha^k)^s \pmod p \equiv \alpha^{d\cdot r+k\cdot s} \pmod p$$

So, we require that :

$$\alpha^x \equiv \alpha^{d\cdot r+k\cdot s} \pmod p$$

According the corollary shown above, the relationship holds **if and only if**:

$$ x \equiv d\cdot r+k\cdot s \pmod {p-1}$$
hence, we get $s$:

$$s\equiv (x - d \cdot r)k^{-1} \pmod {p-1}$$

This is just the construction rule of the signature parameters $s$ follows from.
The condition that $gcd(k, p-1) = 1$ is required since we have to invert the
ephemeral key modulo $p-1$ when computing $s$.

### 3. Conclusion

From the description above, we now know why it is $p-1$, not $p$.

### References

1. 《Rosen, K. H. (2011). *Elementary Number Theory and Its Applications* (6th ed.). Pearson.》
2. 《Paar, C., & Pelzl, J. (2010). *Understanding Cryptography*. Springer-Verlag.》

Comment: I don't know why you gave a huge answer for this question. Clearly, the OP just asked where the inverse of $k$ is calculated. And the Meryem's answer already indicated that it is in $p-1$ by the last line. Please firstly check the other answers. We are in a question/answer site. In general, if not satisfies, the OP can comment for clarification.

Comment: The Meryem's answer really indicated that it is  $p-1$。
I give it why  this is. That is ok?
And I guess robert want to know why it is $p-1$, not $p$
If there is any downside, I apologize.  I am a newcomer.

Comment: They why is also clear, the equation is working on $\bmod p-1$.

Comment: Sorry when I answered it ,I thinked it is not so obvious , I want to clarify it  to the robert. Then the answer should be voted to be deleted?

Comment: I cannot enforce you delete. You are giving many answers that are a cold case. Concentrate mostly on new ones?

Comment: Ok if I can, thanks for your response.

Comment: If you feel that the answers is wrong or missing some parts, go on.

Comment: OK, Thanks for your encouragement, great.